# methods for a peculiar BVP system

Tags: finite-difference, ode, boundary-conditions, nonlinear-equations, collocation

Consider the following system defined on the open interval (-1, 1):

$y_1' = c y_3 \\
     y_2' = c y_4 \\
     y_3' = -f(y_1, y_2)y_2 \\
     y_4' = f(y_1, y_2)y_1 $

given  $ y_3(-1) = 0 = y_3(1) \\
         y_4(-1) = 1, y_4(1) = -1 $

Note that the system **cannot** be reduced to the standard form of two point BVP in $y_3, y_4$ by eliminating $y_1, y_2$.

What methods/packages can I use to solve this system ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'standard form'? Matlab's [`bvp4c`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bvp4c.html) or any collocation implementation should well work for you.

Comment: By standard form,  I meant a system of two-point BVPs in $y_3, y_4$ eliminating $y_1,y_2$. Thank you for your comment, I looked at bvp4c and it does do the job.

Answer (score 2):

It's true that you can't eliminate $y_1,y_2$ to obtain something where every variable you have has appropriate boundary values. However, you can
take derivatives on both sides of the first two equations to get
  $$y_1'' = c y_3' \\
     y_2'' = c y_4' \\
     y_3' = -f(y_1, y_2)y_2 \\
     y_4' = f(y_1, y_2)y_1 $$
and then eliminate $y_3',y_4'$:
$$
  y_1'' = -c f(y_1, y_2)y_2 \\
     y_2'' = c f(y_1, y_2)y_1 
$$
Now you just need boundary values. If you recall that $y_1'=cy_3$ and similarly $y_2'=cy_v$, then they read
$$ 
  y_1'(-1) = 0 = y_1'(1) \\
         y_2'(-1) = 1, \\
         y_2'(1) = -1.
$$
In other words, you have a coupled nonlinear second-order system in $y_1,y_2$ with Neumann boundary values.

Comment: I had thought along similar lines before posting the question. However I started having doubts about the validity of the boundary condition generated this way because, the given ODE system is defined on the open interval (-1,1), and boundary conditions are independently supplied at the end points -1 and 1. Given the boundary condition $y_3(1)$, is it valid to assume that $y_1'(1) = cy_3(1)$ ? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Sure. If your solution is sufficiently smooth, then this condition can be extended from the interior to the boundary.